# Is it possible to update values in Tcl/Tk combo box with new values?

Tags: combobox, tcl, tk-toolkit

I set a list1 as combo box values. later i modifies list1 according to some conditions and i want to display that new list1 values into the combo box values, replacing the old values. it was not working with my code..

```
set list1 [list 1 2 3 4 5]
ComboBox .top.e1  -width 5 -entrybg white -textvariable var1 -values "$list1"
grid config .top.e1 -row 0 -column 1 -sticky "e"


if {$common_list!=""} {
    set ans [tk_messageBox -message "Condition satisfies!" -parent .top -type ok]
    set list1 [list 6 7 8 9 10]
    proc_alpha_1
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code that is reproducible. `ComboBox` is not a default feature in Tk, but `ttk::combobox` is. That could mean that the fix for `ttk::combobox` might not be suitable if this is a different feature. When you use `[list1]`, you are invoking the command/proc `list1` which doesn't exist and which means your code should either give an error, or you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: Yeah.. Its was a small mistake. Actually i meant $list1. Anyway i got the solution and thank you very much to spend time for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set list1 {1 2 3 4 5}
ComboBox .top.e1 -values $list1
pack .top.e1

set list1 {6 7 8 9 10}
# configure ComboBox to use your new list:
.top.e1 configure -values $list1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Now it is working to my expectation.